# Can you evict Ignite cache backups to disk?

Tags: caching, ignite

We would like to keep primary keys in memory and backup keys on disks.  So on re-shuffle, we will accept the performance of reading key/values from disks.

From my research on the ignite documentation, I don't see that option out of the box.  Is there any way to do this via configuration?

If this feature doesn't exist, as a workaround I had the following idea.  If we know our cache takes 1 terabyte, we know with backups it will be 2 terabytes. (Approximately)  If we allocate a little over 1 terabyte in memory and set the eviction policy to disk, will this effectively get us the functionality we want?  That is, will it evict backup copies to disk and leave primaries in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist and your workaround won't work because it will randomly evict primary and backup copies. However, you can probably implement your own eviction policy that will immediately evict any created backup and configure swap space to store this backups.

Note that I see sense only in case you're running SQL queries and/or if you don't have persistence store. If you only use key based access, any lost entry will be reloaded from the persistence store when needed.

Comment: Yeah, we don't use key based access.  We actually don't use SQL either, we are broadcasting a lambda and executing on local entries.  Thanks!

Comment: Just getting to writing this now.  Within the Eviction Policy we are thinking of using an Affinity function in order to determine which keys are primary and which keys are backup.  Does that seem like an appropriate approach?  Also, not sure if it matters but we have also implemented our own affinity function.